# using dart route package url got error 404

Tags: routes, dart

Here's my main.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:route/client.dart';
import 'urls.dart';
void main() {
  var router = new Router()
  ..addHandler(homeUrl, showHome)
  ..addHandler(galleryurl, showGallery)
  ..listen();
  HttpRequest.getString("home.html").then((html){
        querySelector("#container").innerHtml = html;
      });
}

void showHome(String path){
  HttpRequest.getString("home.html").then((html){
    querySelector("#container").innerHtml = html;
  }); 
}

void showGallery(String path){
  HttpRequest.getString("gallery.html").then((html){
    querySelector("#container").innerHtml = html;
  });
}
```

urls.dart:

```
library urls;
import 'package:route/url_pattern.dart';

final homeUrl = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/');
final homeUrlWithFile = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/index.html');
final contacturl = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/contact');
final galleryurl = new UrlPattern(r'(.*)/gallery');

final allUrls = [homeUrl, contacturl, galleryurl];
```

and my body in index.html:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </nav>
  <main id="container">
  </main>
  <footer class="footer" >
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">here's footer</div>
  </footer>
  <script src="packages\jquery_for_pub\1.11.0\jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="packages/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>

  <script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
```

my problem is when i go to localhost:8080/gallery , i got error 404. but if i open localhost:8080 and click on gallery link, it works.

i want to redirect it to index.html and the #container's content changed to gallery when it opened in localhost:8080/gallery.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pushState (default) you need server support to redirect a request to the correct URL. This is often delegated to nginx for example.
Alternatively you can disable pushState and use fragments instead

```
var router = new Router(useFragment: true)
  ..addHandler(new UrlPattern(r'(.*)#something'), (_) => view = 'home')
```